# How To Take Gradient Color As KgradientColor in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, gradient

I Just Created The Const Colors And I Want Make Const Of Gradient Color.
If AnyOne Know Please Help Me.

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const bgcolor = Color(0xFFF6F6F6);
const fontColor = Color(0xFF151515);
const fontparaColor = Color(0xFF8B8B8B);
const iconOnTapColor = Color(0xFF8B8B8B);
const iconColor = Color(0xFF1F7CFE);
const buttonBgColor = Color(0xFF016AFF);
const diverColor = Color(0xFFB9B9B9);
const buttonTextColor = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
const hintTextColor = Color(0xFFB3B3B3);
const fontWeight = FontWeight.w500;
```

[This Is The Image  Where I Want To Add Gradient Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNWVc.png)

Comment: can you provide image of what type of gradient you want to create

Comment: I Add The Image You Can Check it. I Want Add The Gradient In Storage Bar.

Comment: What is gradient exactly you are trying to do. Because I barely find any difference in background.

Comment: what is KGradientColor?

Comment: I Just Want Made Reusable Code Of Gradient For Project. So, Didn't have To Write The Code Every Single Time.

Comment: oh are you trying to make a gradient for a single color like the material colors shade property

Answer (score 1):

```
static const themeGradient = LinearGradient(
    colors: [
      Color(0xff6D59A6),
      Color(0xffB04F98),
      Color(0xffEF3A4B),
    ],
  );
```

Comment: Okay Let Me Try

Comment: The argument type 'LinearGradient' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'

Comment: You need to pas in decoration of Container

Comment: const BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: themeGradient,
           
                  ),

Comment: Okay, It's Compulsory Add BoxDecoration In it.

Comment: Gradient is not a Color type, in flutter we should use box decoration for gradients

Comment: Yes it is compulsory to add Box Decoration

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).